# Windows Phone c# how to catch global hook

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have simple app:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CameraButtons.ShutterKeyPressed += OnButtonFullPress;           
}
private void OnButtonFullPress(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //camera button pressed
}
```

When my app is active, all is great, but, when my app is not active, i cant catch, when camera button were pressed.

Is this possible with default SDK?

Comment: No, you can't do that. If your application is not active the camera button press event will launch the default camera application.

Comment: Anton Sizikov, maybe, can i catch else buttons? Lock phone, sound buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to set your application as a default camera app on windows phone 8, but this feature is only available for 'special' developers like Microsoft, Nokia or other hardware companies. So it's not possible for you, most probably.

http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-phone-8/234751-changing-default-camera-app.html

Also if you look at the application lifecycle you'll see that after user minimizes your app it might be tombstoned and even unloaded from the memory. So, you loose the control over the device resources. That means that you can't get any events except the awake event.

The third option you have is to run the app under the lock screen, but it doesn't fit you as well. There is a limited set of api's you can use in this mode. (Location and Audio).

So I'm sorry, but you can't do anything so far.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible for third-party developers. You can only access the hardware buttons while your applications is running.